# What does Google and another search engine do with sites that collect information

Tags: seo, google-search, search-engine-indexing, search-engines

What do Google and another search engine do with sites that collect information and display it in categories? This information is not unique in the internet.

How well those sites rank? Do they get penalized?

Comment: I don't see the problem and detailed description.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site)

Answer (score 4):

If a website has **just duplicate content** from another site, it **will not rank** well. Google might even give up crawling the site after a while.

If a website combines **data from multiple sources** and creates a **unique composition of content** that has an actual **benefit for users**, it **can rank very well**. Look at most flight and hotel aggregators. They all have the same content. There are only so many flight routes in the world, and every website will display the same airports, IATA codes, and times. Yet, these websites manage to rank by combining it all in a unique landing page.